# Change background color on a cell if that cell doesn't have a number entered

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Trying to change the background color of a cell if there isn't a number entered in the cell and the date in an adjacent cell is older than today. in libreoffice calc. I have tried conditional format but can't get it to work. I can get the date part to work but not with the addition of the cell not having a number. I tried ISBLANK but that didn't work. Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment under the answer.  Also, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula as criteria for conditional formatting::

```
AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(A2));B2<TODAY())
```

(assuming `C8` is the first cell to be formatted conditionally).

If you want to define that formatting rule for a range of cells, you can still reference the first cells of that range:

[image]